# Local and remote ip adresses are same, I cannot ssh to server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, vpn

I am using OpenVPN to ssh my office computer. My home ip(inet) adress is 192.168.1.30 and my office ip adress is 192.168.1.100. After OpenVPN connection I can not ping my office computer. I think router tries to resolve remote ip adress locally.

When I use my phone's internet my ip adress becomes 192.168.10.30 and I have no problem. I can ssh to remote computer after VPN connection.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: OpenVPN should be introducing an additional network interface, usually called `tun0` on Linux, with its own IP address. If your VPN is using IP addresses beginning with 192.168.1.x, you can't use the same range of IP addresses on your LAN and expect no conflict. Most routers allow you to change the internal IP range. Perhaps you could use 192.168.0.x. It's also possible that OpenVPN isn't working at all. It's hard to tell from your question. Where to look for problems depends on how you're launching OpenVPN.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.